# hbase standalone and zookeeper standalone in single machine

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, apache-zookeeper

Is this possible to run both Hbase and external zookeeper in standalone mode in single machine?

It stucks with clientPort issue.

Please clarify?

Answer (score 3):

Yes , it is possible. 
To do that , you will have to change the client port of external zookeeper server. 
Go to conf directory of external zookeeper. Open the zoo.cfg file. If its not there, rather zoo_sample.cfg is there,  then do `mv conf/zoo_sample.cfg conf/zoo.cfg`  to create it.
 In zoo.cfg file, change the default port no of clientPort=2181 to 2182 . Also change the dataDir to some directory you wish .
For example - I will do 
 `dataDir=/home/ckant/zookeeper1
 clientPort=2182`  on my machine.
 Now run `./zkServer.sh` to start the server .
 To connect the client to this zkserver run `./zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2182`. Your client is now connected to the external zookeeper server running on port 2182. 
Any time to connect to zookeeper started by hbase, just change the port number to 2181 in above command.

Comment: @PrabhuR - can you accept the solution then. It may help other people in future.

Comment: can we change the port number of zookeeper started by hbase to some other than 2181 default value? if so, how?